# How to use PHP to connect to an Informix database?

Tags: php, database, informix

First, I would like to introduce the problem.

I have a Informix database that is currently used by 300 staffs (average is around 100,000 records/query) that make this server work slowly. Current architecture is:

Informix DB ⟷ Web Application

Now I want to implement the new system by adding new MySQL server with the following architecture

Informix DB ⟷ MySQL Server ⟷ Web Application

In MySQL Server I would like to copy the database from Informix to MySQL server by using PHP + Cronjob.

**The questions are:**

1. Is there has any ODBC / JDBC driver (must be FREE!!) in LINUX for connecting to Informix?
2. How to use it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ifx.php ?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an extension for connecting to Informix. See the manual pages here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ifx.php

You can also use the PDO extension with its Informix driver: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php

In both cases, you need to ensure that your copy of PHP has been built with those extensions. You can check what extensions are in your copy of PHP by seeing the output of the `php_info()` function. If it doesn't include the relevant extensions, then you'll need to rebuild your copy of PHP to include them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
/b
another problem is i can't remote to Infomix Server (the console)  but i have only an account that using for database connection

Comment: @user746167: you do not need to be on the database server machine to be able to access the database - if the DBMS is set up to listen on a network port.

Comment: Is PDO require to generate the extension from the infomix server or not ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user: No: You can use either the basic informix extension **or** the PDO extension with informix driver. They are two separate ways of achieving the same thing. I would recommend PDO as the first choice, since it gives you a common API with other databases, which will make it easier if you're also working with mySQL. But if you prefer, you could just use the basic informix extension and not worry about PDO.

Comment: Dear, Spudley :: Thank you. i will trying on the PDO first as your recommended. :)

Comment: To use the PDO extension it required to install the IBM Infomix SDK but the IBM's Website now it can't register. How can i do it T____T

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Informix ClientSDK (CSDK) includes both ODBC and JDBC drivers, and can be obtained free of charge.  If you want support for the software, there is a charge, of course.

If you go to http://www.informix.com/ (the `www` is crucial; omit it and you get to the IBM home page), you get directed to http://www.ibm.com/software/data/informix/.  The free database editions include CSDK in the download.  It is possible to get CSDK standalone, without the server, too.  And IBM Informix Connect (I-Connect) is the runtime part of CSDK.

You can connect to Informix from PHP with PDO Informix or PDO IBM modules.

Comment: but i can see only the trial version T___T

Comment: Informix Developer Edition is a full-featured non-trial version available for free (but you can't use it in production - check the T's & C's carefully).  There's also the Informix Innovator-C Edition.

Comment: how ever i don't have the IBM ID....

So, I can't download it  T___T

Did you have it ?
Thanks